# Why i can't create persistence authentication (firebase) in my login component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, frontend, redux-toolkit

**Hello everyone**,
I'm doing a react test and I want to implement firebase authentication persistence in my Login component. I know you need to use setPersistence for this, but for some reason, the authentication doesn't persist after a reboot. In general, my authentication and registration work correctly (I have several components - Register.jsx , Login.jsx and Form.jsx which serves as the base for Register and Login. It's just that when the page is reloaded, the authentication is reset as before, without any errors. Also i have redux-toolkit in my app. Can you help me? What am I doing wrong?

*This is my base.js file:*

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE,
};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const database = getDatabase(app);

export default app;
```

*This is my Login component:*

```
import { Form } from './Form';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setUser } from '../store/slices/userSlice';
import {
    getAuth,
    setPersistence,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    browserSessionPersistence,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const auth = getAuth();

    const handleLogin = async (email, password) => {
        try {
            await setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence);
            signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(({ user }) => {
                console.log(user);
                dispatch(
                    setUser({
                        email: user.email,
                        id: user.uid,
                        token: user.accessToken,
                    })
                );
                navigate('/');
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Invalid email or password', error);
        }
    };
    return <Form title='sign in' handleClick={handleLogin} />;
};

export { Login };
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to clarify ***specifically*** what is resetting app-side? See [mcve].

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The code you shared only handles the moment when the user actively logs in, so when they first enter their credentials.

When you reload the page, Firebase actually restores the credentials the user entered before, but the code you shared doesn't handle that scenario. To pick up the restored user, use the `onAuthStateChanged` as shown in the first code sample in the documentation on [getting the active user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```